# Time Dependent Anomaly Detection in Unsupervised Learning

Tags: time-series, unsupervised-learning, anomaly-detection

I have a multivariate time series anomaly detection problem where data is time series and some of the variables follow specific patterns depending on time.

For example, let's say variables A, B and C take high but consistent values every 60 minutes, which would look like anomaly from the perspective of other time windows, however knowing the context of the data, I know that this is not anomalous, because these very high values occur periodically and are expected. However it would be anomaly if it were to occur in other timeframe rather than every 60 minutes.

Therefore I want to include this knowledge of 'time' and 'periodicity' in my model, so that these periodic instances will not be marked as anomaly when they occur in periodicity but will be marked as anomaly other times.

Since I have 2k features, I don't think simply adding date/time as another column can help.
So what is the best way to model this kind of time dependent anomaly detection where periodicity exists?

Comment: With 2k features I would first recommend some feature reduction. Anomaly Detection on such high dimensionality is challenging in general. What is the nature of your features? Makes sense to try first something simple like PCA, maybe UMAP. Autoencoder if that is not good enough.

Comment: If you have few distinctly different kinds of time-periods, and you know these in advance, you can use one anomaly detector for each such kind of period. Then merge the anomaly scores afterwards